# Why isn't my mod_authnz_external not working?

Tags: apache-httpd

I am trying to use mod_authnz_external (using pwauth) to secure my Apache 2.4 site. So far, everything I've tried isn't working - I can curl content from my webserver without auth. Here is the current effective config:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wdennis/44aa082914e9d427f4c1/raw/7048e8e3a1d7ccc35ae3eb6f6afb1004f6f0caf9/apache_effective_config_20160225.txt

What must I do to get this config working as intended?

Comment: The wind blows... a tumbleweed rolls by. Somewhere in the distance, a coyote howls.